# square her bites

Tags: phrases

I wonder what this means: square her bites

> Unlike many at the academy, she was not particularly athletic. But she had earned a black belt in taekwondo, passed all the required endurance tests and flourished in the classroom. She also mastered the required manner of eating for plebes, **squaring her bites** and taking no more than three chews before swallowing.

Answer (score 1):

> Formal posture during mealtimes in the US military involved sitting upright and holding the bent arm in a way that it formed a right angle at the elbow. The body-arm positions formed a 3-sided square-like shape, and the eating utensil pointing towards your mouth forming the 4th side of the square. Hence a US military meal would be a squarely eaten meal.

and more:  http://www.saywhydoi.com/square-meal-origin-and-meaning-why-do-we-say-square-meal/

Comment: What you have quoted here is listed in the link as an "entertaining (yet untrue) theor[y] for the origin of “square meal”. It says: "This theory, entertaining as it is to act out, has not been backed up by evidence."

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.